# I want to revert my master branch to state 8 commits ago

Tags: git, revert

I just realized I introduced a memory leak somewhere in the last 8 commits.
Easiest solution is to revert to 8 commits ago, then carefully add the changes
back in. What is the easiest way of doing this?

Thanks!

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Take a look at [`git bisect`](http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/git-bisect.html). It sounds like exactly what you are looking for.

Basically, you tell it a known good point and a known bad point in your history, and then it helps you perform a binary search until you find the offending commit.

Here's a tutorial on its use: http://www.kernel.org/pub/software/scm/git/docs/user-manual.html#using-bisect

But, if you don't want to do it that way, create a temporary branch where you are right now and either do a bunch of `git reset HEAD^` to go up one commit at a time, or do `git reset HEAD~8` and then `git cherry-pick <sha1>` for each subsequent commit between you and your temporary commit.

Answer (score 1):

Clone your master to another branch, then on master `git reset --hard` to the commit in question. Then use `git cherry pick` to introduce each reverted commit from the backups branch to the master branch and inspect. If all ok then proceed to next commit and so on.

Please read up on the commands i stated, before actually proceeding if you're not familiar with them. :-)

Comment: I think you mean `git reset`, not `git revert`.

Comment: I fixed that. Git reset is useful if you want to throw away working directory changes too.